# Not found : Diagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX) template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

With visual studio 2015 RC, I had used "Diagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX) template" to create live code analyser where I could generate a nugget package as well as VSIX file.

The template is not available after the release of VS 2015 RTM. I have explicitly installed Roslyn SDK but still the template is not there in my Visual Studio 2015 RTM

Where can I get the similar template for visual studio 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've updated the template to indicate that it is only applicable with a Target Framework of .NET 4.5.2 or higher. Take a look at the Target Framework dropdown at the top of the New Project dialog.

Comment: I even need to set 4.6 platform, as template was absent under 4.5.2